# How to install a LDAP schema with python-ldap?

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

I have a LDAP schema in a `.ldif` file that I would like to use python-ldap to install the schema on my LDAP server. My context is the installation process of a python application that needs some custom LDAP schemas.

There is a bit of documentation about [ldif](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/reference/ldif.html) and [schemas](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/reference/ldap-schema.html) in python-ldap, but I do not know where to start.

How can I install a schema with python-ldap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ldap.modlist
import ldif


with open("myschema.ldif") as fd:
    parser = ldif.LDIFRecordList(fd)
    parser.parse()

for dn, entry in parser.all_records:
    add_modlist = ldap.modlist.addModlist(entry)
    conn.add_s(dn, add_modlist)  # where 'conn' is a LDAP connection
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is what @azmeuk has written before.

The long answer is: it depends on the format of your LDIF file. If it contains modify statements then you cannot easily parse the file with python-ldap.

Please check my question at [Process LDIF modify records with python-ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69817029/process-ldif-modify-records-with-python-ldap) to see what I'm talking about.